# How to redirect to another page from OnAutherization Of MVC in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, authorization

I am new to angularjs and working on asp.net MVC with angularjs. I am using angularjs states to redirect another page. When I redirect to login page from OnAuthorization of MVC login page renders in the current page rather than separate page

```
 public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
       if(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true) 
           ||  filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true))
           return;

       CurrentUserToken = sessionManager.CurrentUserToken;

       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUserToken))
           HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }

protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            //string destinationUrl = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl("http://localhost:49363/Account/SignIn", filterContext.HttpContext);

            //JavaScriptResult result = new JavaScriptResult()
            //{
            //    Script = "window.location='" + destinationUrl + "';"
            //};
            //result.ExecuteResult(filterContext);

            //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403; //There is no HTTP status code for session timeout. We are using this code as it stands for "Forbidden" which is closer.
            //filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            //{
            //    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            //    Data = new { error = true, httpCode = 403, status = "Error", message = "Session expired. Please relogin." }
            //};
            var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
            var verifyEmailUrl = url.Action("SignIn", "Account", null);
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(verifyEmailUrl);
           // filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { Action = "SignIn", Controller = "Account" }));
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { Action = "SignIn", Controller = "Account" }));
        }
    }
```

Please give me some suggestions to get out of this issue.